# Se puede seleccionar automáticamente de un SELECT?

Tags: javascript, html5, html-select

Hola quisiera saber si con Javascript puedo cambiar un SELECT...
El tema es así, es una web que carga los datos de forma asíncrona dependiendo del valor seleccionado, en realidad toma el valor de archivos Json ya descargados, por defecto ya está seleccionada una opción que en ejemplo es la "C" y yo quiero cambiarla con Javascript por la opción "A" así veo los datos correspondientes a esa opción.  Son  muchos los SELECT a los cuales le cambio la opción por eso quisiera saber si es posible cambiarlos con Javascript.

Sé que es posible tocar botones pero con los  SELECT no entiendo si es posible o no....

```
<div id="area22">
<select id="22">
<option value="A">AAA</option>
<option value="B">BBB</option>
<option value="C" selected="selected">CCC</option>
</select>
</div>

<div id="cont22">
CONTENIDO correspondiente a CCC.
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplemente selecciona el elemento `select` y asígnale el `value` deseado.

**Con JS puro**

```js
function inicio(){
  let select = document.getElementById("22");
  select.value = "A";  
}
```

```html
<body onload="inicio()"> 
  <div id="area22">
  <select id="22">
  <option value="A">AAA</option>
  <option value="B">BBB</option>
  <option value="C" selected="selected">CCC</option>
  </select>
  </div>

  <div id="cont22">
  CONTENIDO correspondiente a CCC.
  </div>
</body>
```

**Con JQuery**

```js
$(function(){
  $("#22").val("A");
  //Cambiamos el atributo selected entre opciones
  $("#22 option[value=A]").attr({selected: true});
  $("#22 option[value=C]").removeAttr("selected");
  
  //Asignamos la opción seleccionada
  $("#cont22").html($("#22 option:selected").text());
  
  //Evento onchange
  $("#22").on("change",function(){
   $("#cont22").html($('option:selected',this).text());
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body> 
  <div id="area22">
  <select id="22">
  <option value="A">AAA</option>
  <option value="B">BBB</option>
  <option value="C" selected="selected">CCC</option>
  </select>
  </div>

  <div id="cont22">
  CONTENIDO correspondiente a CCC.
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hola Kiko_L el valor se cambia pero NO se cambian los datos, solo se cambian si lo hago manualmente, quizás porque alguna función esté esperando el evento onchange u onselect (si es que hay), así que aunque le quite el atributo selected con removeAttribute y le asigne el value los datos siguen como si no pasara nada...

Comment: ¿Cuando dices datos te refieres al contenido de cont22?

Comment: No termino de entender a qué te refieres.

Comment: Exacto, el contenido NO CAMBIA si lo hago con Javascript, solo si lo hago manualmente.

Comment: Edito la respuesta con el cambio. Lo he hecho en jQuery. Si lo quieres en Javascript puro, dime y lo hago cuando tenga algo más de tiempo.

Comment: Puede ser que al usar la consola de GC no sea lo mismo que usar un archivo externo con funciones Javascript?

Comment: Pues depende de qué se esté almacenando en la consola de manera global, por ejemplo pero en una sesión limpia no debería haber diferencia.

Answer (score 0):

Me falta el contenido correspondiente pero me lo he inventado. Espero que sea lo que necesites.

```js
window.onload = inicio;

function inicio(){ 
  _22.options[0].selected = true;
  cont22.innerHTML = "CONTENIDO correspondiente a " + _22.options[0].text;
}


function alCambiar(){
cont22.innerHTML = "CONTENIDO correspondiente a " +  _22.options[_22.selectedIndex].text;
}

_22.addEventListener("change",alCambiar)
```

```html
<div id="area22">
  <select id="_22">
  <option value="A">AAA</option>
  <option value="B">BBB</option>
  <option value="C" selected="selected">CCC</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="cont22">
  CONTENIDO correspondiente a CCC.
</div>
```

Comment: Hola, mira es una web, es decir la pagina no la manejo yo, yp pego las funciones en la concola y espero los resultados, pero si bien funcionan los cambios en los atributos y todo funciona correcto con la función,  hay un contenido que debe cambiarse y no se bien cual es el evento que dispara la función que cambia el contenido dependiendo del valor de los SELECT, pero aunque SI se cambia el valor, los datos que deben mostrarse siguen estáticos.

Comment: He cambiado de id="22" a id="_22" porque id="22" empieza con un número, y es ilegal. No tenia idea que no podías cambiar.